# Why should I use applicative functors in functional programming?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, functor

I'm new to Haskell, and I'm reading about functors and applicative functors. Ok, I understand functors and how I can use them, but I don't understand why **applicative** functors are useful and how I can use them in Haskell. Can you explain to me with a simple example why I need applicative functors?

Comment: It is only a link I can give, but [here](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Applicative_functor) is a nice description of Applicative Functors with an examples.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How do you use Control.Applicative to write cleaner Haskell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104446/how-do-you-use-control-applicative-to-write-cleaner-haskell)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

[Applicative functors](http://www.soi.city.ac.uk/~ross/papers/Applicative.html) are a construction that provides the midpoint between functors and [monads](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_%28functional_programming%29), and are therefore more widespread than monads, while more useful than functors. Normally you can just map a function over a functor. Applicative functors allow you to take a "normal" function (taking non-functorial arguments) use it to operate on several values that are in functor contexts. As a corollary, this gives you effectful programming without monads.

A nice, self-contained explanation fraught with examples can be found [here](http://learnyouahaskell.com/functors-applicative-functors-and-monoids#applicative-functors). You can also read [a practical parsing example](http://www.serpentine.com/blog/2008/02/06/the-basics-of-applicative-functors-put-to-practical-work/) developed by Bryan O'Sullivan, which requires no prior knowledge.

Comment: There are helpful links , but I don't think they can replace a short simple example focused to answer the question, with all unimportant details removed as much as possible.

Answer (score 35):

Applicative functors are useful when you need sequencing of actions, but don't need to name any intermediate results. They are thus weaker than monads, but stronger than functors (they do not have an explicit bind operator, but they do allow running arbitrary functions inside the functor).

When are they useful? A common example is parsing, where you need to run a number of actions that read parts of a data structure in order, then glue all the results together. This is like a general form of function composition:

```
f a b c d
```

where you can think of `a`, `b` and so on as the arbitrary actions to run, and `f` as the functor to apply to the result.

```
f <$> a <*> b <*> c <*> d
```

I like to think of them as overloaded 'whitespace'. Or, that regular Haskell functions are in the identity applicative functor.

See "[Applicative Programming with Effects](http://www.soi.city.ac.uk/~ross/papers/Applicative.pdf)"

Answer (score 12):

Conor McBride and Ross Paterson's [Functional Pearl](http://strictlypositive.org/Idiom.pdf) on the style has several good examples.  It's also responsible for popularizing the style in the first place.  They use the term "idiom" for "applicative functor", but other than that it's pretty understandable.

Answer (score 9):

It is hard to come up with examples where you *need* applicative functors. I can understand why an intermediate Haskell programmer would ask them self that question since most introductory texts present instances derived from Monads using Applicative Functors only as a convenient interface.

The key insight, as mentioned both here and in most introductions to the subject, is that Applicative Functors are between Functors and Monads (even between Functors and Arrows). All Monads are Applicative Functors but not all Functors are Applicative.

So necessarily, sometimes we can use applicative combinators for something that we can't  use monadic combinators for. One such thing is [`ZipList`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#t:ZipList) (see also [this SO question for some details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18210765/instance-alternative-ziplist-in-haskell)), which is just a wrapper around lists in order to have a **different Applicative instance** than the one derived from the Monad instance of list. The Applicative documentation uses the following line to give an intuitive notion of what `ZipList` is for:

```
f <$> ZipList xs1 <*> ... <*> ZipList xsn = ZipList (zipWithn f xs1 ... xsn)
```

*As pointed out [here](http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2009-April/059088.html), it is possible to make quirky Monad instances that almost work for ZipList.*

There are other Applicative Functors that are not Monads (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2120509/applicative-functors-other-than-monads-and-ziplist) SO question) and they are easy to come up with. Having an alternative Interface for Monads is nice and all, but sometimes making a Monad is inefficient, complicated, or even impossible, and that is when you *need* Applicative Functors.

---

*disclaimer: Making Applicative Functors might also be inefficient, complicated, and impossible, when in doubt, consult your local category theorist for correct usage of Applicative Functors.*

Answer (score 7):

In my experience, Applicative functors are great for the following reasons:

Certain kinds of data structures admit powerful types of compositions, but cannot really be made monads.  In fact, most of the abstractions in functional reactive programming fall into this category.  While we might technically be able to make e.g. `Behavior` (aka `Signal`) a monad, it typically cannot be done efficiently. Applicative functors allow us to still have powerful compositions without sacrificing efficiency  (admittedly, it is a bit trickier to use an applicative than a monad sometimes, just because you don't have quite as much structure to work with).

The lack of data-dependence in an applicative functor allows you to e.g. traverse an action looking for all the effects it might produce without having the data available.  So you could imagine a "web form" applicative, used like so:

```
userData = User <$> field "Name" <*> field "Address"
```

and you could write an engine which would traverse to find all the fields used and display them in a form, then when you get the data back run it again to get the constructed `User`.  This cannot be done with a plain functor (because it combines two forms into one), nor a monad, because with a monad you could express:

```
userData = do
    name <- field "Name"
    address <- field $ name ++ "'s address"
    return (User name address)
```

which cannot be rendered, because the name of the second field cannot be known without already having the response from the first.   I'm pretty sure there's a library that implements this forms idea -- I've rolled my own a few times for this and that project.

The other nice thing about applicative functors is that they *compose*.  More precisely, the composition functor:

```
newtype Compose f g x = Compose (f (g x))
```

is applicative whenever `f` and `g` are.  The same cannot be said for monads, which has creates the whole monad transformer story which is complicated in some unpleasant ways.  Applicatives are super clean this way, and it means you can build up the structure of a type you need by focusing on small composable components.

Recently the `ApplicativeDo` extension has appeared in GHC, which allows you to use `do` notation with applicatives, easing some of the notational complexity, as long as you don't do any monady things.

Answer (score 6):

One good example: applicative parsing.

See [real world haskell] ch16 http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/using-parsec.html#id652517

This is the parser code with do-notation:

```
-- file: ch16/FormApp.hs
p_hex :: CharParser () Char
p_hex = do
  char '%'
  a <- hexDigit
  b <- hexDigit
  let ((d, _):_) = readHex [a,b]
  return . toEnum $ d
```

Using functor make it **much shorter**:

```
-- file: ch16/FormApp.hs
a_hex = hexify <$> (char '%' *> hexDigit) <*> hexDigit
    where hexify a b = toEnum . fst . head . readHex $ [a,b]
```

**'lifting' can hide the underlying details of some repeating code. then you can just use fewer words to tell the exact & precise story.**

Comment: You've got a strange idea of "much shorter" -- the applicative version is 7 characters longer!

Comment: @Daniel Wagner:-_-||, Oh my.. you has good insight of the code, I have to confess. I actually means 'vertically shorter' :)

Comment: Well, it can be written shorter using common functions from the Control.Monad library: `char '%' >> liftM (toEnum . fst . head . readHex) (replicateM 2 hexDigit)`.

Comment: Or, using the `count` combinator from `Parsec`, and switching back to applicative style: `toEnum . fst . head . readHex <$> (char '%' >> count 2 hexDigit)`

Answer (score 3):

I would also suggest to take a look at [this](http://wiki.ifs.hsr.ch/SemProgAnTr/files/ApplicativeFunctorsInHaskell.pdf)

In the end of the article there's an example

```
import Control.Applicative
hasCommentA blogComments =
BlogComment <$> lookup "title" blogComments
            <*> lookup "user" blogComments
            <*> lookup "comment" blogComments
```

Which illustrates several features of applicative programming style.