# What's wrong with my altered version of zip?

Tags: haskell, compiler-errors

I'm trying to write a function that is similar to zip but that won't discard extra elements. I feel like I've made a really dumb error somewhere.

Example input:

```
zipMaybe [1,2,3] [1,2]
```

Desired output:

```
[(Just 1, Just 1), (Just 2, Just 2), (Just 3, Nothing)]
```

---

```
zipMaybe :: [a] -> [b] -> [(Maybe a, Maybe b)]
zipMaybe (a:as) (b:bs) = (Just a, Just b) : zip as bs -- line with error
zipMaybe (a:as) [] = (Just a, Nothing) : zip as []
zipMaybe [] (b:bs) = (Nothing, Just b) : zip [] bs
zipMaybe _ _ = []
```

This, however won't compile.

```
Test.hs:2:49:
    Couldn't match type `a' with `Maybe a'
      `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for
            zipMaybe :: [a] -> [b] -> [(Maybe a, Maybe b)]
          at Test.hs:1:13
    Expected type: [Maybe a]
      Actual type: [a]
    In the first argument of `zip', namely `as'
    In the second argument of `(:)', namely `zip as bs'
    In the expression: (Just a, Just b) : zip as bs
```

Comment: You're calling `zip` instead of recursively calling your `zipMaybe`.

Comment: You might like [`align`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/these-0.3/docs/Data-Align.html).

Comment: @DanielWagner thanks, `padAlign` does exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should call `zipMaybe` recursively instead of backing off to vanilla `zip`, which has the wrong type.

```
zipMaybe :: [a] -> [b] -> [(Maybe a, Maybe b)]
zipMaybe (a:as) (b:bs) = (Just a, Just b) : zipMaybe as bs
zipMaybe (a:as) [] = (Just a, Nothing) : zipMaybe as []
zipMaybe [] (b:bs) = (Nothing, Just b) : zipMaybe [] bs
zipMaybe _ _ = []
```

Btw., there's a shorter definition of this function:

```
zipMaybe (x:xs) (y:ys)  =  (Just x, Just y) : zipMaybe xs ys
zipMaybe xs     []      =  [(Just x, Nothing) | x <- xs]
zipMaybe []     ys      =  [(Nothing, Just y) | y <- ys]
```

Comment: How about `map (\x -> (Just x, Nothing)) xs` instead of `map`, `zip`, and `repeat`?

Comment: @DanielWagner: then I'd prefer a comprehension. See updated answer.