# Can you give me an example of how to use Ramda lift?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

I am reading ramda documentation

```
const madd3 = R.lift((a, b, c) => a + b + c);

madd3([1,2,3], [1,2,3], [1]); //=> [3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 6, 5, 6, 7]
```

It looks like a really useful function. I can't see what would be a use case for it.

Thanks

Comment: Hmm, I thought we'd cleaned up that documentation.  A clearer example would be `madd3([100, 200], [30, 40], [5, 6, 7]) //=> [135, 136, 137, 145, 146, 147, 235, 236, 237, 245, 246, 247]`.  The answers given are great, but see also https://stackoverflow.com/q/36558598/1243641.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This function can only accept numbers:

```
const add3 = (a, b, c) => a + b + c;
add3(1, 2, 3); //=> 6
```

However what if these numbers were each contained in a functor? *(i.e. a thing that contains a value; an array in the example below)*

```
add3([1], [2], [3]); //=> "123"
```

That's obviously not what we want.
You can "lift" the function so that it can "extract" the value of each parameter/functor:

```
const add3Lifted = lift(add3);
add3Lifted([1], [2], [3]); //=> [6]
```

Arrays can obviously hold more than one value and combined with a lifted function that knows how to extract the values of each functor, you can now do this:

```
add3Lifted([1, 10], [2, 20], [3, 30]);
//=> [6, 33, 24, 51, 15, 42, 33, 60]
```

Which is basically what you'd have got if you had done this:

```
[
  add3(1, 2, 3),    // 6
  add3(1, 2, 30),   // 33
  add3(1, 20, 3),   // 24
  add3(1, 20, 30),  // 51
  add3(10, 2, 3),   // 15
  add3(10, 2, 30),  // 42
  add3(10, 20, 3),  // 33
  add3(10, 20, 30)  // 60
]
```

Note that each array doesn't have to be of the same length:

```
add3Lifted([1, 10], [2], [3]);
//=> [6, 15]
```

So to answer your question: if you intend to run a function with different sets of values, lifting that function may be a useful thing to consider:

```
const results = [add3(1, 2, 3), add3(10, 2, 3)];
```

is the same as:

```
const results = add3Lifted([1, 10], [2], [3]);
```

Answer (score 5):

Functional programming is a long and mathematical topic, in particular [the part dealing with monads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44965/what-is-a-monad) and [cathegory theory in general](https://nikgrozev.com/2016/03/14/functional-programming-and-category-theory-part-1-categories-and-functors/). But it is worth to take a look at it, [here is a funny introduction with pictures](http://adit.io/posts/2013-04-17-functors,_applicatives,_and_monads_in_pictures.html).

In short, lift is a function that will take a *n-arguments* function and will produce a function that takes *n* **wrapped-values** and produces another resulting **wrapped-value**. A lift that take a one-argument function is defined by the following type signature

```
 // name :: f is a wrp-value => function -> wrp-value -> wrp-value
 liftA :: Applicative f   => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

**Wait... Wrapped-value?**

I will introduce briefly Haskell, only to explain this. In haskell, an easy example of wrapped-value is *Maybe*, Maybe can be a wrapped-value or nothing, that is also a wrapped-value. The following example applies a function to a Maybe containing a value, and a empty Maybe.

```
> liftA (+ 8) (Just 8)
Just 16
> liftA (+ 8) Nothing
Nothing
```

The list is also a wrapped-value, and we can apply functions to it. In the second case liftA2 applies two-argument functions to two lists.

```
> liftA (+ 8) [1,2,3]
[9,10,11]
> liftA2 (*) [1..3] [1..3]
[1,2,3,2,4,6,3,6,9]
```

This **wrapped-value** is an Applicative [Functor](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/functors-categories-61e031bac53f), so from now I will call it Applicative.

Maybe Maybe you are starting to lose interest from this point... 
But someone before us has got lost on this topic, [finally he survived and published it as an answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44306719/2739274).

Lets look at what did he see...

...

[image: What did you see? (xkcd comic)]

**He saw Fantasy Land**

> In fantasy-land, an object implements [`Apply`](https://github.com/fantasyland/fantasy-land#apply) spec when it has
>   an `ap` method defined (that object also has to implement
>   [`Functor`](https://github.com/fantasyland/fantasy-land#functor) spec by defining a `map` method).

- Fantasy-land is a fancy name to a functional programming spec in
  javascript. Ramda follows it.
- Apply is our Applicative, a
  **Functor** that implements also an **ap** method.
- A **Functor**, is something that has the **map** method.

So, wait... the Array in javascript has a map...

```
[1,2,3].map((a)=>a+1) \\=> [ 2, 3, 4 ]
```

Then the Array is a Functor, and map applies a function to all values of it, returning another Functor with the same number of values.

**But what does the [ap](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#ap) do?**

> ap applies a list of functions to a list of values.
>
> Dispatches to the ap method of the second argument, if present. Also
>   treats curried functions as applicatives.

Let's try to do something with it.

```js
const res = R.ap(
  [
    (a)=>(-1*a), 
    (a)=>((a>1?'greater than 1':'a low value'))
  ], 
  [1,2,3]); //=>  [ -1, -2, -3, "a low value", "greater than 1", "greater than 1" ]

console.log(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ramda@0.26.1/dist/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

The ap method takes an Array (or some other Applicative) of functions an applies it to a Applicative of values to produce another Applicative flattened.

The signature of the method explains this

```
[a → b] → [a] → [b]
Apply f => f (a → b) → f a → f b
```

**Finally, what does lift do?**

Lift takes a function with *n* arguments, and produces another function that takes *n* **Aplicatives** and produces a flattened **Aplicative** of the results.

In this case our Applicative is the Array.

```js
const add2 = (a, b) => a + b;
const madd2 = R.lift(add2);

const res = madd2([1,2,3], [2,3,4]); 
//=> [3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 6, 5, 6, 7]

console.log(res);
// Equivalent to lift using ap
const result2 = R.ap(R.ap(
  [R.curry(add2)], [1, 2, 3]),
  [2, 3, 4]
  );
//=> [3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 6, 5, 6, 7]
console.log(result2);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ramda@0.26.1/dist/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

These *wrappers* (Applicatives, Functors, Monads) are interesting because they can be anything that implements these methods. In haskell, this is used to wrap unsafe operations, such as input/output. It can also be an error wrapper or a tree, even any data structure.

Comment: In general, `lift`, or more precisely `liftA2` is equivalent to `ap(map(x))`, not `ap(ap(x))`. So this is Ramda specific and deviates from the standard.

Comment: @reify: Ramda [does implement `liftN`](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/blob/master/source/liftN.js#L25-L30) (and therefore `lift`) with an initial `map`, reducing `ap` calls on the result.

Answer (score 2):

What hasn't been mentioned in the current answers is that functions like `R.lift` will not only work with arrays but any well behaved [Apply](https://github.com/fantasyland/fantasy-land#apply)<sup>1</sup> data type.

For example, we can reuse the same function produced by `R.lift`:

```
const lifted = lift((a, b, c) => a + b - c)
```

With functions as the Apply type:

```
lifted(a => a * a,
       b => b + 5,
       c => c * 3)(4) //=> 13
```

Optional types (dispatching to `.ap`):

```
const Just = val => ({
  map: f    => Just(f(val)),
  ap: other => other.map(otherVal => val(otherVal)),
  getOr: _  => val
})

const Nothing = {
  map: f    => Nothing,
  ap: other => Nothing,
  getOr: x  => x
}

lifted(Just(4), Just(6), Just(8)).getOr(NaN) //=> 2

lifted(Just(4), Nothing, Just(8)).getOr(NaN) //=> NaN
```

Asynchronous types (dispatching to `.ap`):

```
const Asynchronous = fn => ({
  run: fn,
  map: f    => Asynchronous(g => fn(a => g(f(a)))),
  ap: other => Asynchronous(fb => fn(f => other.run(a => fb(f(a)))))
})

const delay = (n, x) => Asynchronous(then => void(setTimeout(then, n, x)))

lifted(delay(2000, 4), delay(1000, 6), delay(500, 8)).run(console.log)
```

... and many more. The point here is that anything that can uphold the interface and laws expected of any Apply type can make use of generic functions such as `R.lift`.

<sub>1. The argument order of `ap` as listed in the fantasy-land spec is reversed from the order supported by name dispatching in Ramda, though is still supported when using the `fantasy-land/ap` namespaced method.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Basically it is taking a cartesian product and applies a function to each array.

```js
const
    cartesian = (a, b) => a.reduce((r, v) => r.concat(b.map(w => [].concat(v, w))), []),
    fn = ([a, b, c]) => a + b + c,
    result = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1]]
        .reduce(cartesian)
        .map(fn);

console.log(result); // [3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 6, 5, 6, 7]
```