# Access temp variables in R.pipe. Ramda

Tags: functional-programming, ramda.js, pointfree

Let's say I want to calculate the average cost:

```
const products = [
  {
     cost: 300
  },
  {
     cost: 700
  }
];
```

So first pluck the cost property, summarize them, then divide by the nr of items.

```
const calcualteAveragePrice = R.pipe(
      R.map(R.prop('cost') // [300, 700]
      R.sum, // 1000
      R.divide(??) // How do I divide with the number of items here??
    )
```

In the last step I need to divide by the number of items. Since it's point free, I cant do `arr.length`.

Comment: You have a few options, but being point free for the sake of being point free is costing you here. I'd convert it to a reduce and call it a day. I mean, `Array.prototype.map` passes the whole array as the third argument to the callback, and since Ramda dispatches to the map method if present on the collection it does the same, but you can't use that with piping. You could also do something kinda icky like stuff the length in a var in an outer scope and partially apply it to `R.divide`.

Comment: Yeha I have working reduce function. Was curious how/if this could be done with pff.

Comment: @JaredSmith: I suppose the Ramda docs are a bit confusing on this.  Ramda dispatches to that method only if it's not a type which Ramda handles itself.  Here that includes Arrays, Objects, and Functions.  So it won't actually dispatch.

Comment: @ScottSauyet yes, the docs make it sound like it uses the native method when available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ramda does have a [`mean`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#mean) function (as well as a [`median`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#median) one.)  So that will make your solutions fairly simple:

```js
const calculateAveragePrice = compose (mean, pluck( 'cost'))

const products = [{cost: 300}, {cost: 700}]

console .log (
  calculateAveragePrice(products)
)
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script>
<script>const {compose, mean, pluck} = R                             </script>
```

Or of course you could write `pipe (pluck('cost'), mean)` instead.  I prefer `compose` for one-liners, and `pipe` for anything else, but that's just a matter of taste.

But if you didn't know that Ramda supplied this, you could write your own point-free `average` function with [`converge`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#converge):

```js
const average = converge(divide, [sum, length])
```

`converge` and its cousin [`useWith`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#useWith) are designed to make it easier to write point-free versions of code.  I always include a warning that point-free should rarely be a goal on its own, however.  It's useful only when it serves to improve the readability of the code.  Both `converge` and `useWith` tend to be questionable on that score.  There is an alternative that is more standard in the FP world: the function [`lift`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#lift):

```js
const average = lift (divide) (sum, length)
```

`lift` transforms a function that accepts values of certain types to one that accepts *containers* of values of those values.  And since a function that returns a value of a given type can be considered a container (squint hard if necessary), `lift (f) (g, h)` is something equivalent to `(x) => f (g (x), h (x))`.  (There's more information in the SO question, *[Can't wrap my head around “lift” in Ramda.js](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36558598)*.)

`converge` is slightly more flexible, but I always use `lift` if I can.  It feels more standard.

Comment: you showed me something new about `lift`ing functions :)

Comment: And if we make `lift`'s interface variadic and name it `doA` or `doM` we have something that resembles applicative/monadic do notation pretty much.

Comment: @bob: I'm curious as to your comment.  In once sense, I can see an obvious link, `lift (f) (g, h)` binds `f`'s two parameters to the results of applying arguments to `g` and `h`.  But I don't see an obvious extension of this API.  `lift` is already variadic in that `lift(f)(g, h, i, j)` ~= `(x) => f((g(x), h(x), i(x), j(x))`, but I suspect you mean something else.

Comment: I didn't know that `lift` is already variadic, sorry. However, when I use this term I usually assume the curried form, ie. `liftAn` is equiv to `return f ap t1 ap t2 ap tn`