# What is the purpose of an applicative functor?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

Can anyone share a good real life situation when a function with the following signature would be useful?

```
f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

I can't really see where I would need something like the schoolbook examples from [learn-you-a-haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/functors-applicative-functors-and-monoids) `[(+),(*)] <*> [1,2] <*> [3,4]`

Comment: Gabriel Gonzalez's [series](http://www.haskellforall.com/2012/08/the-category-design-pattern.html) [of](http://www.haskellforall.com/2014/04/scalable-program-architectures.html) [articles](http://www.haskellforall.com/2014/04/model-view-controller-haskell-style.html) on `Monoid`s demonstrates [very useful properties of `Applicative`s](http://www.haskellforall.com/2014/07/equational-reasoning-at-scale.html).

Comment: One common idiom is [applicative parsing](https://github.com/pcapriotti/optparse-applicative).

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are practical uses of applicative style?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7103864/what-are-practical-uses-of-applicative-style)

Comment: yeah, might be, too bad we got some nice answers here already

Comment: Partial application! I use `(<*>) :: f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b` with infix `fmap`, `(<$>) :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b` so that if `f :: a -> b -> c -> d` and `fa :: f a` etc then `f <$> fa <*> fb <*> fc :: f d`. Notice that `f <$> fa :: f (b -> c -> d)` and `f <$> fa <*> fb :: f (c -> d)` so that finally `f <$> fa <*> fb <*> fc :: f d`. I almost never use `<*>` without `<$>`. Your question arises because you don't usually think to make things of type `f (a -> b)`, but these exist as intermediate values. I could have `(+) <$> readLn :: IO (Int -> Int)` so that `(+) <$> readLn <$> readLn :: IO Int`

Answer (score 6):

Applicatives can be used for lots of stuff that you might also do with a monad, but that don't really need the stronger features of that class. (More precisely, whenever *the “shape” of the functor doesn't depend on values within*, then `Applicative` is sufficient.) For instance, an action like

```
foobar :: IO [String]
foobar = do
   fooTxt <- readFile "foo.txt"
   barTxt <- readFile "bar.txt"
   return $ zip (lines fooTxt) (lines barTxt)
```

could as well be written

```
foobar = zip <$> (lines <$> readFile "foo.txt")
             <*> (lines <$> readFile "bar.txt")
```

In this case, that makes it merely a tad shorter, but in other cases it may also improve performance (because `Applicative` is less general, more optimisations are possible) or allow you to make code more generic than when you use the `Monad` interface.

Answer (score 5):

The most common use I have of it is to use multiple Monadic (or in this case Applicative) values for a function. A really common way I use it is for constructors.

Consider:

```
randomAge :: Rand StdGen Int
randomHeight :: Rand StdGen Double
randomWeight :: Rand StdGen Double

data Person = Person { age :: Int, height :: Double, weight :: Double }

randomPerson :: Rand StdGen Person
randomPerson = Person <$> randomAge <*> randomHeight <*> randomWeight

-- If we only had Monads...
randomPerson' :: Rand StdGen Person
randomPerson' = liftM3 Person randomAge randomHeight randomWeight
-- or worse...
randomPerson'' = randomAge >>= \ra -> randomHeight >>= \rh -> randomWeight >>= \rw -> return $ Person ra rh rw
```

Or this example from [FPComplete's tutorial on the JSON parser Aeson](https://www.fpcomplete.com/school/starting-with-haskell/libraries-and-frameworks/text-manipulation/json):

```
instance FromJSON Person where
 parseJSON (Object v) =
    Person <$> v .: "firstName"
           <*> v .: "lastName"
           <*> v .: "age"
           <*> v .: "likesPizza"
 parseJSON _ = mzero
```

Or this example from the [Real World Haskell chapter on Parser Combinators](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/using-parsec.html):

```
ghci> let parser = (++) <$> string "HT" <*> (string "TP" <|> string "ML")
```

For the most part Applicatives are useful when you have `f :: a -> b -> c` and you have `m a` and `m b` and you want an `m c`.

Edit: That said there are other uses. For example, Applicative can be used as a really good way to modify traversable data structures. E.g. applying a tree to a value, by having a tree of functions, thereby turning a value into a tree. Or doing non-deterministic list operations without list comprehension syntax.

It can have some unexpected applications. For example, using the `->` Monad:

```
> (<*>) (+) (+1) 2
5
```

That last one was a bit more esoteric and isn't likely to be used in a practical circumstance but it shows that you can use Applicatives in many ways.

Answer (score 3):

It's the basic building block (along with `pure`) for other very useful functions like `liftA2` (which you could think of as "`fmap` over two containers" and not be too far off the mark):

```
liftA2 :: Applicative f => (a -> b -> c) -> f a -> f b -> f c
liftA2 f fa fb = pure f <*> fa <*> fb
```

So suppose you want to add all combinations of values of two lists `xs, ys :: [Integer]`, you could do it this way:

```
liftA2 (+) xs ys
```

Though more commonly we write this:

```
(+) <$> xs <*> ys
```

You are right to be puzzled why would somebody ever write `[(+),(*)] <*> [1,2] <*> [3,4]`—I think it's a very artificial example.  99% of the time, `Applicative` is used, you fundamentally have *one* function that takes two or more arguments, and are looking to apply it to the values inside a functor that implements `Applicative`.

One way of looking at it is that we could alternatively define `Applicative` and associated functions like this:

```
-- Not the real definition
class Functor f => Applicative f where
    pure :: a -> f a

    -- Like `fmap` but for two-argument functions:
    liftA2 :: (a -> b -> c) -> f a -> f b -> f c

-- `<*>` and `liftA2` are interdefinable, as shown further up and just here:
(<*>) :: Applicative f => f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
ff <*> fa = liftA2 ($) ff fa
```

But the reason `<*>` is picked as the class method is that it makes it very easy to write `liftA2`, `liftA3`, etc.:

```
liftA2 :: Applicative f => (a -> b -> c) -> f a -> f b -> f c
liftA2 f fa fb = pure f <*> fa <*> fb

liftA3 :: Applicative f => (a -> b -> c -> d) -> f a -> f b -> f c -> f d
liftA3 f fa fb fc = pure f <*> fa <*> fb <*> fc

liftA4 :: Applicative f => (a -> b -> c -> d -> e) -> f a -> f b -> f c -> f d -> f e
liftA4 f fa fb fc fd = pure f <*> fa <*> fb <*> fc <*> fd
```

The `Applicative` class is very nearly the minimum functionality needed to support this "map with a function of multiple arguments" pattern, which is a useful thing in tons of cases.

Comment: It also seems to me that the `Applicative` laws are easier to express and at least somewhat more intuitive using `<*>` than using `liftA2`.

Comment: @dfeuer: But perhaps even easier if we used `<,> :: Applicative f -> f a -> f b -> f (a, b)` as the basic operator instead. The associative law becomes `(x <,> y) <,> z == x <,> (y <,> z)`.  But the problem with that is that we don't want `Applicative` instances allocating useless pairs at runtime...

Answer (score 1):

As leftaroundabout mentioned, whenever the "shape" of each "action" doesn't depend on the values "produced" by the previous one, `Applicative` is sufficient.

This may be a shape in a very literal way. For example, one context for `>>=` is that `t >>= f` takes values stored in the leaves of a tree `t`, applies `f` to each value to produce a new subtree, and grafts each subtree onto the tree in place of its corresponding leaf. This operation, however, doesn't work for a *balanced* tree, because there's no telling how large/deep a tree `f` will produce each time. However, `<*>` may still make sense, because the grafted trees will all have the same shape, maintaining balance.